# Подскажите модуль графики, чтоб был на весь экран?

Tags: python

Подскажите, может есть такой простой графический модуль для питона, чтоб был на весь экран. Чтобы задавать картинку, линию, кружок?

Comment: спасибо, то что искал!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри тут: [GUI Programming in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming).

Answer (score 0):

PyGame, биндинги к SDL